# AIX ftpd - how to set umask for a given user?

Tags: aix, ftp, umask

I know how can I change the umask settings for all the users using ftpd, but how can I change the umask for a given user using FTPD?

AIX/6100-05-02-1034
FTP server (Version 4.2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [AIX ftpd](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/aix/v6r1/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.aix.cmds%2Fdoc%2Faixcmds2%2Fftpd.htm) doesn't provide per-user `umask` settings. You can set a global `umask` value with the `-u` switch, but neither the command line nor the configuration file allow you to set this on a per-user basis.

Note that you can set the `umask`, and run `chmod`, from the client side with `SITE` commands:

```
SITE UMASK 002
SITE CHMOD 600 your_file
```

Answer (score 0):

```
chsubserver -c -v ftp -p tcp "ftpd -l -u077
refresh -s inetd
```

Comment: Hi! It would be great if you could expand your answer to explain how it works and why it solves the problem, in as much detail as is relevant.